# Make front page for SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I'm looking to make a home page for a set of SSRS reports with just title and a few hyperlinks to other reports.
How do you make the title fit the size of your screen rather than Report Manager just showing its actual size? 
When looking at Report Manager there are big blocks of white down the side of the screen depending on the monitor size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve this is to set the report `Zoom` property to `Page Width` in the URL, for example:

`http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks/Employee_Sales_Summary&rc:Zoom=Page%20Width`

There are a lot of other things you can configure via the URL as well - such as hiding toolbars, passing parameters, displaying breadcrumb navigation, etc - which you may find interesting to have a look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Comment: So there is no where to do it in the properties?

Comment: I tried this but it remained the same
http://ukgiocrsdev01/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fAvailability+Matching+Reporting%2fFrontPage&rc:Zoom=Page%20Wi

Comment: @DeanFlaherty  Please actually read answers and any associated documentation before blindly applying small fragments of the given answer and then complaining it doesn't work.  You URL needs to be in the format `http://<SSRS Server Name>/reportserver?/<Report Address>&rc:Zoom=Page Width`, which yours is not.